# useNavigate: Navigate to external Link

Tags: react-router-dom

on Clicking of a button, I want to perform an async operation and after that navigate user to an external website as shown below:

`navigate("https://wwww.google.com?q=ABC")`

But here's the problem:

while using navigate, my url changes like this, because for some reason it's assuming relative path:

`http://localhost:3000/https://wwww.google.com?q=ABC`

Can someone help me understand what is going wrong? I also tried setting `replace` to `true` but no luck there as well.

Comment: `react-router-dom` doesn't deal with external navigation. As you've seen it will only append the path target to the current base URL within the same domain. Use `window.location.href` to change location to an external URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "https://wwww.google.com?q=ABC";
```